# discord.js make exception for message author

Tags: javascript, random, discord, discord.js

I have this code which chooses a random user and displays their name and what they won, the problem is it can also make the user who sent the giveaway message the winner and the same with bots. How can I make an exception for the msg.author?

```
if(msg.content.startsWith('-giveaway'))
    {
      const suggestion = msg.content.slice(10);
      const user = msg.guild.members.random();
      let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setTitle('Prize : ' + suggestion)
        .addField('Host : ', msg.author)
        .addField('Nyertes : ', user)
        .setFooter('Verzió 1.1')
        .setTimestamp()
        msg.channel.send(embed);
        console.log(`${user.user}`).catch(console.error);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter out the message author from the user list before selecting a random user:

```js
const userList = msg.guild.members.filter(user => user.id !== msg.author.id || !msg.author.bot || msg.member.roles.some(role => role.name === 'RoleName') || msg.member.roles.some(role => role.id === 'ROLE_ID'));
const user = userList.random();
```

Comment: It worked for the message author but is there any way to filter a role or just the bots by their ID's one by one?

Comment: I edited my answer and added other filters that can be helpful to you